# How to sort data by different classes?

Tags: r, ggplot2, nlp

I have a data frame, there are 6 topics and 10 terms for each topics. I want to sort terms based on probability of appearance divided by topics, and then visualize using bar chart. However, The output only sorted the first topic and the other topics remain unchanged.

Here is my R code.

```
library(tidytext)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(forcats)

top_terms_df <- as.data.frame(top_terms)
top_terms_df <- rownames_to_column(top_terms_df, var = "term")
top_terms_df <- gather(top_terms_df, key = "topic", value = "prob", -term)
top_terms_df$topic <- as.numeric(gsub("Topic", "", top_terms_df$topic))

# Sort the terms by probability within each topic
top_terms_df <- top_terms_df %>%
  group_by(topic) %>%
  mutate(term = factor(term, levels = term[order(prob, decreasing = TRUE)]))

ggplot(top_terms_df, aes(x = term, y = prob, fill = factor(topic))) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge") +
  facet_wrap(~ topic, scales = "free_y") +
  labs(x = "Term", y = "Probability", fill = "Topic")
```

My output looks like

[image]

as we can see, only terms in the first topic have been sorted.

Comment: could you provide some data?